# Prefered way of custom styling for 2013 apps?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, branding

I created some autohosted apps ( for Office 365) and by default there's a script `setStyleSheet();` that makes the app look like the rest of the page. This is something I want but I would also like to override a few things, for example I want the same border color around text boxes as on the rest of the page but instead of the white button make it blue (among other things).

I don't want to remove the call to `setStyleSheet()` because then I would have to style every single element of the app, I can't add a reference to a custom stylesheet in the masterpage because the app is in an iframe. I prefer to not have a bit of `<style></style>` elements in each app.

What's considered the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Like I mentioned the app is loaded in an iframe so whatever stylesheet reference I add to the masterpage won't get picked up.

By default the app is blended in with the rest of the page look and feel with this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Set the style of the client web part page to be consistent with the host web.
    function setStyleSheet() {
        var hostUrl = ""
        if (document.URL.indexOf("?") != -1) {
            var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
            for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                p = decodeURIComponent(params[i]);
                if (/^SPHostUrl=/i.test(p)) {
                    hostUrl = p.split("=")[1];
                    document.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"" + hostUrl + "/_layouts/15/defaultcss.ashx\" />");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (hostUrl == "") {
            document.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/_layouts/15/1033/styles/themable/corev15.css\" />");
        }
    }
    setStyleSheet();
</script>
```

Sure I can load another stylesheet there but I wanted to check if this is the intention or if there are any other (new) smarts around branding in SP2013 for this case?

Answer (score 1):

The way I achieved in my project was as follows:

- Editing this part in head section in my master page

  ```
  <SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration1" Name="Themable/corev15.css" runat="server" />
  <SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration2" Name="/Style Library/css/general.css" runat="server" After="corev15.css" />
  ```

General.css is an own css that exists in the site Style Library. So in that css write the style you need to overwrite as `!important`.

For example, you could use this class to overwrite the grey border in "Find a File" textbox in a document library

```
.ms-InlineSearch-Outline-Empty
{
    border-color: #FF0000 !important;
}
```

The .ms-InLineSearch-Outline-Empty is a class that belongs to SharePoint. Search the ones you wanna change and change it!

Comment: `!important` is not always necessary. It depends on when your CSS is being loaded.

Comment: Hi, I updated my original post a bit

Comment: Then, why don't you try to use JQuery approach? something like var $currentIFrame = $('#IDOfTheIFrame'); 
$currentIFrame.contents().find("head").append($("<style type='text/css'>  .my-class{border-color: #HEXCOLOR};  </style>"));

You can put this code in the master page